# Can I declare local temporary table in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle12c

I'm trying to declare local temporary table using the example from [Oracle / PLSQL: LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLES](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/local_temp.php). But when I try to insert it into `sqlplus' CLI` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it does not execute anything and I don't know what to do next to complete the command except pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> interrupting command inputing:

```
SQL> DECLARE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE suppliers_temp
( supplier_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  supplier_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  contact_name varchar2(50)
);  2    3    4    5
  6
  7  ;
  8  ^C
```

To execute this query I've logged in as **SYSTEM** user.

Why this example does not work for me?

Comment: I think you will find an answer here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3714968

Comment: Not only is LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE not a thing in Oracle, that's not even valid Oracle syntax. So the teaching is, and it's a really important teaching, **there's a lot of nonsense on the internet**. So you should learn to use [the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm)  instead of trusting random websites, even ones which feature highly in Google searches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`local temporary tables` aren't a thing in the Oracle RDBMS. Instead, you can have a [Global Temporary Table (GTT)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#sthref5118) (which creates a permanent table, but the data is held at session level) or, introduced in 18c, you can have a [Private Temporary Table (PTT)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/private-temporary-tables-18c) (the table definition and data are held at session level).

Both are similar to the standard create table statement, so to create a GTT that drops the rows when you commit, you would do something like:

```
create global temporary table table_name (col1 number, col2 varchar2(20))
   on commit delete rows;
```